# Trying to get dynamic sparkline

Tags: jquery, sparklines

I'm trying to dynamically add sparklines without success.  I need to add 'sparklike101', 'sparklike201', etc

ifaceID would be a number.  It just doesn't work.  Not sure if I'm doing it right.  I havce snipet of the code below.

```
var addChart=function(ifaceID, ifaceRow) {
var inn = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
$('.sparkline'+ifaceID).sparkline(inn,{type: 'line'});                        
ifaceRow.append('<td><span class="sparkline'+ifaceID+'">Loading...</span></td>');
    }
    })}
for (var i in  msg.d.Rows) { var ifaceID = msg.d.Rows[i][0]; var ifaceRow = $('<tr></tr>'); table.append(ifaceRow); addChart(ifaceID, ifaceRow);  }
```